# Rails 5.1 + Webpack.... images in CSS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm trying to figure out how to use the `--webpack` method for a very simple Rails 5.1 app.

I'm trying to use it for managing both JS as well as CSS (`scss`, specifically).

This is so insanely frustrating though because there's no docs I can find anywhere how to do even the most basic stuff.

How do I link an image from within my css file?

Like this: `background-image: asset-url('header.jpg')`

Comment: Have you tried to read the [documentation](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#webpacker) ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use default webpack-rails configuration. Please follow paths that I added in comments

your layout should include special tag:

```
 # app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

<head>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'include_js_logic_here' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'include_stylesheet_here' %>
</head>
```

include_stylesheet_here.js

```
# app/javascript/packs/include_stylesheet_here.js
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css'; #exmple how to get styles from library 
import './stylesheets/application.scss';
```

application.scss

```
#app/javascript/packs/stylesheets/application.scss
body{
  background-image: url('../img/arrow-right-red.svg');
}
```

paths for images is:

`app/javascript/packs/img/arrow-right-red.svg`

Comment: I was able to load the image like this: `background-image: url('~img/arrow-right-red.svg');`